# How to delete all files having starting name match in phonegap

Tags: jquery, cordova

can you please tell me How to delete all files having starting name match in phonegap.
in other words it will delete all files from the folder with starting name match.
I write this code when i delete only one file.

```
function removefile(){
    fileSystem.root.getFile("readme.txt", {create: false, exclusive: false}, gotRemoveFileEntry, fail);
}

function gotRemoveFileEntry(fileEntry){
    console.log(fileEntry);
    fileEntry.remove(success, fail);
}

function success(entry) {
    console.log("Removal succeeded");
}

function fail(error) {
    console.log("Error removing file: " + error.code);
}
```

I want to delete all file with stating name **"read"**

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below code will read all the files in an specific folder and delete the files which have started with name as 'read'.

```
      document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

        function onDeviceReady() {


        window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, 
        function gotFS(fileSystem) {
            fileSys = fileSystem;
        }
        , fsFail);

    fileSys.root.getDirectory("myFolder/", {create: true, exclusive: false},  
        function(parent) {
            folder=parent;
        }
        , dirFail);

        //Creating a reader
        var directoryReader = folder.createReader();
        // Get a list of all the entries in the directory
        directoryReader.readEntries(ReaderSucces,readerFail);   

        function ReaderSucces(entries){

        var i,len;
        len = entries.length;
        for (i=0; i<len; i++) {
            if (entries[i].isDirectory) {
                 var directoryReaderIn = entries[i].createReader();
                directoryReaderIn.readEntries(ReaderSucces,readingFail); 
            }
            if(entries[i].isFile==true)
            {
                  entries[i].file(deleteFile, readingFail);
            }
        }
    }

    var fsFail = function(error) {
            alert("failed with error code: " + error.code);
    };                  
    var dirFail = function(error) {
        alert("Directory error code: " + error.code);
    };
    var readerFail = function(error) {
        alert("Reading Directory error code: " + error.code);
    };          
    var readingFail = function (error){
        console.log("Reading Files error code: "+error.code);
    };

function deleteFile(file) {

    if(file.name.substring(0,3)=='read')
    {

     file.remove(success, fail); 
    }
 }
function success(entry) {
    console.log("Removal succeeded");
}

function fail(error) {
    console.log("Error removing file: " + error.code);
}
```